# mysql order by multiple columns including flag

Tags: mysql

I could use help with SQL query building. Here's my situation:

I want to order results by 3 columns. This is the situation. I have list of attached items, and needs to select only one in that list and which one depend on its "importance". Importance is determined by this rules:

- if some item have bigger severity, take that one
- if severity is the same, and top flag is on some item, take that one
- if severity and top is the same, take one with bigger priority
  (if all are the same, doesn't matter which one to take)

The problem is that top parameter, as it can contain any text, and the rule should be if it is empty (''), null or E in it (E as empty) flag is not set and only sev and prior should be used and if any other value is inside top, that flag is on and 2nd rule should be used.

It looks strange I know (that column) but actually I just get values from outside and process them as they are.
I cant use `ORDER BY severity,top,priority` as for top either DESC or ASC is wrong, so I don't know how to proceed. Some example setup is [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e57c/1). 
Any ideas?
Thx in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a computed `ìmportance` column in your `SELECT` statement. Use a `CASE` for it, so that when `top` is empty, null or 'E', `importance` is 0. Otherwise, `importance` is 1.

Then `ORDER BY severity,ìmportance,priority`

Comment: thx,good suggestion. Can i avoid using procedure or multiple queries on this one? As you see in my fiddle,i am using subquery,and i found out that you cant use alias in subquery ORDER BY. My idea was to use SELECT item,severity,(CASE WHEN top = '' OR top = 'E' OR top IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS importance,priority,attached 
FROM history i1 and then ORDER BY severity,importance,priority in subquery but importance is not recognized there.

Comment: This looks like a separate question. Could you make a new question for it? There's not enough info here to answer it properly.

Comment: i can, but actually in that other question i cant explain much more then i did in this one(my starting question). Point is for attached items i need to select only one with higher importance (i explained how importance works here). If you need more info i can update my question here? As this is in my opinion the same problem, dont know if i should open another one. The other thing you can see in my fiddle is the attached column that define what items are attached together.

Comment: No, you can't order by a column in the outer query if that column isn't present in the subquery. Can you look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e57c/4 and see if that does what you want? It's still not clear to me what this query is trying to achieve, so it might be that the latest fiddle doesn't help.

Comment: hi,thx again for your help. I am little stupid today (not enough sleep i guess :D). I did not need subquery at all. I just needed to order them and show the most important one.I guess split function confused me here. Here it is the fiddle that works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e57c/10. Problem solved,and ill accept your answer now.